# unable to access sonatype Nexus from browser

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, nexus

I am unable to access Nexus via browser. I am using Ubuntu GCP instance. I have enabled the UFW and made sure that the port 8081 is added to it, also tried changing the port but it is not working, tried running nexus on docker as well. In all these cases, Nexus service is running that I have verified. When I used the command netstat -na | grep LISTEN command, I can see that the port 8081( default port of Nexus) is not listening. Any suggestions or comments will be helpful

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already verified that Google Firewall isn't blocking packets? You can always use a utility like nmap from outside to check a network port status.

Comment: I have verified this. I am able to access all other applications like sonarqube, jenkins, via browser but not this application. In all other applications, the port is listening and I have checked that using grep | Listen command but in nexus case, the port is not listening and I think that is why I am not able to access it Thanks !